# Bouncy Castle, RSA: transforming keys into a String format

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm using RSA (Bouncy Castle API) in my C# project. I generated the keypair with this method:

```
RsaKeyPairGenerator r = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
r.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = r.GenerateKeyPair();

AsymmetricKeyParameter private_key = keys.Private;
AsymmetricKeyParameter public_key = keys.Public;
```

Now I want to save them in a txt file but the problem is that I can't convert them to a string format. I read in another post that keys must be serialized using:

```
PrivateKeyInfo k = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(private_key);
byte[] serializedKey = k.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
```

Is it the right way? If yes, what should I do after this? Just convert them from byte[] to String?

Answer (score 31):

You could also use PemWriter to store them in PEM format:

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(keys.Private);
pemWriter.Writer.Flush();

string privateKey = textWriter.ToString();
```

Now **privateKey** contain something like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but just change the last line, instead of `string privateKey = pemWriter.ToString();` try `string privateKey = textWriter.ToString();`

Answer (score 11):

Well, I don't know about the RSA-specific side, but once you've got an opaque binary string (i.e. it could contain any arbitrary data) the best bet for text conversion is [`Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) which you can reverse with [`Convert.FromBase64String(string)`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.convert.frombase64string.aspx&ei=0vhkTfTgD4uIhQenrbTgBw&usg=AFQjCNHEnON6JHlXz0DCGZwbLkRo7lW_fA).

**Do not** use `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` and `Encoding.GetBytes(string)` for this - the binary data *isn't* text in a particular encoding, and shouldn't be treated as such. You're almost bound to lose data if you try this.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I did as u said and as result i got this **MIICdwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmEwggJdAgEAAoGBAJ7s/B4XNHmNa9LwZ91z...** I think it should be a BigInteger no ? because in RSA we use numbers (p, q ...)

Comment: The method name (GetDerEncoded) suggests that the returned data contains all RSA key parameters (p, q, ...) in DER encoded format.

Comment: @Rami: Is your aim to get something you can "rehydrate" back to a PrivateKeyInfo? If so, you don't need to know the integers etc... you just want to make sure you can serialize to a byte array (and then to a string) and vice versa.

Comment: @Christian thanks, so i have all the parameters back in one format. cool, but how can i divide it to get values of the (p, q...)? any methods ? thanks again.

Comment: @Rami: Look at the rest of the Bouncy Castle API docs for a reverse operation to GetDerEncoded and ToAsn1Object.

Answer (score 4):

This might be what you are looking out for:
http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/04/serializing-deserializing-rsa-public-private-keys-generated-using-bounty-castle-library

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
        RsaKeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        rsaKeyPairGenerator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), XXX));

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = rsaKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

        PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(keys.Private);
        // Write out an RSA private key with it's asscociated information as described in PKCS8.
        byte[] serializedPrivateBytes = privateKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
        // Convert to Base64 ..
        string serializedPrivateString = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPrivateBytes);

        SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keys.Public);
        byte[] serializedPublicBytes = publicKeyInfo.ToAsn1Object().GetDerEncoded();
        string serializedPublicString = Convert.ToBase64String(serializedPublicBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the bouncycastle certificate to a .net certificate. The function to do this is in the bouncycastle lib (i believe it's in a class called DotNetUtilities). The RSACryptoServiceProvider has a function:

```
ToXmlString(bool includePrivateKey).
```

Which gives you an x representation of a certificate with if you want the private key containing all the components serialized to base64 seperately, exponent, modulus, and d (private exponent).