# Encrypt and store a private+public key with Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle, private-key

I created a AsymmetricCipherKeyPair with the ECKeyPairGenerator and want to store the private and public key.

I found the following classes and methods to archive this:

```
PrivateKeyFactory.EncryptKey(...)  
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreateEncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(...)
```

What is the recommend API to use?

But what algorithm should be used?
I tested "BCObjectIdentifiers.bc_pbe_sha1_pkcs12_aes128_cbc" and got an exception "attempt to use non-PBE algorithm with PBE EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo generation"

I also tested "PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC" and it took ages to complete.

So is there a recommend way to store (and read in later) a private and public key with Bouncy Castle C# ?

Comment: Do you just need to store the private key or do you want the key to be wrapped (that is, encrypted). Because the question is about storing, and the examples point to PBE (password based encryption)?

Comment: I need at first storing the keys. And the API is only encryption + encoding. Maybe you can show both ways?

Comment: Have you tried to directly use the PemWriter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090624/bouncy-castle-rsa-transforming-keys-into-a-string-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, those are the right classes. However BC had bugs in the bindings for the AES-based PBE encryption algorithms, which I've only just now fixed in CVS.

Comment: I am also struggling with this same problem - Do I need the updated code?

Comment: Found it - need to use one of these algorithms (PBE algorithms supported by PBEUtil: PBEwithMD2andDES-CBC, PBEwithMD2andRC2-CBC, PBEwithMD5andDES-CBC, PBEwithMD5andRC2-CBC, PBEwithSHA1andDES-CBC, PBEwithSHA1andRC2-CBC, PBEwithSHA-1and128bitRC4, PBEwithSHA-1and40bitRC4, PBEwithSHA-1and3-keyDESEDE-CBC, PBEwithSHA-1and2-keyDESEDE-CBC, PBEwithSHA-1and128bitRC2-CBC, PBEwithSHA-1and40bitRC2-CBC, PBEwithHmacSHA-1, PBEwithHmacSHA-224, PBEwithHmacSHA-256, PBEwithHmacRIPEMD128, PBEwithHmacRIPEMD160, and PBEwithHmacRIPEMD256.)